# Copy, from Multiple Text files, Transpose Row 0 and Row 1, and Paste into One CSV File

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, transpose

I have been working on this for a couple days now.  My previous attempts to copy, from multiple text files, transpose row 0 and row 1, and paste onto one CSV file, were too complex, and I couldn't get it working before.  Now, I'm trying a new approach to do this.  Here is the code that I'm testing.

```
### master mapping table
import glob
path = r'C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/all_files/'

all_files = glob.glob(path + '*.txt')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in all_files:
    print(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = '\t', index_col=None, header=0)
    df_top = df.head(1)
    df_trans = df_top.T
    df.append([filename, df_trans])
    
df_files = pd.concat(df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df_files.to_csv('C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/master_mapping.csv')
```

Here's the error that I'm seeing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-98-13055a9e7ad2>", line 15, in <module>
    df_files = pd.concat(df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 284, in concat
    sort=sort,

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 310, in __init__
    "first argument must be an iterable of pandas "

TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

In the final version of the CSV file, I would like to see the file name in ColumnA, the transposed row 0 in ColumnB, and the transposed row 1 in ColumnC.  Can someone point out my error so I can get this working correctly?  Thanks so much!!

NOTE: I am looping through 3,500 text files.  Maybe I have to do this in chunks...not sure...

Comment: It looks like you are not including all of your imports. What import does `pd` come from? From pandas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem comes from here: df_top = [filename,df_top]

I am trying to join the file name to the transposed version of the first 2 rows in the text file.  If I just transpose the first 2 rows, it seems to work fine.  When I try to add in the file name, before transposing the two rows, nothing works.